# Loading Assemblies in c# application at runtime not present in application working directory

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# console application that requires some 3rd party assemblies(DLL). On dev machine, I know about the location of these assemblies so I can add them as reference to VS2010 project. But I am not sure of these assemblies path at client(user) machine.
I can get these assemblies location from an environment variable or by an registry value ( may be added by 3rd party tool or by user). 
So how will my application load these assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the assemblies are installed on the client, they are automatically loaded because they should be in the GAC. if not, they should be in the same folder as the .exe, or you can load them programmatically with the Appdomain.AssemblyResolve event. This event is fired if an assembly can't be found:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {            
        string assemblyName = args.Name.Remove(args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

        string s = @"C:\dlls\" + assemblyName;

        if (File.Exists(s))
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(s);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

//EDIT:
Watch out with this, there are sometimes a lot of assemblies that can't be found, and it's usually not a problem because it just searches on other places. But if you decide to rewrite this and try to load all assemblies which aren't found, i.e. remove the file.exists, your code will break.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Copy Local` property of the referenced assembly to `true`, your third party assemblies will be copied to the bin directory near your executable.

[image]

This means you'll have those dll in the same directory as your executable when you will install your application on another machine, so there won't be any issue to load those assemblies.

Comment: in this way if there is an update in that application assemblies      (3rd party assemblies) , it will not be reflected back in my application.As my application will be using old one's present in local directory.

Comment: @programmer108 Maybe you should elaborate more about your use case so we can provide a more appropriate answer. Is this a compile time issue? Deployment issue? Installation issue? What kind of update are you talking about (program update once it's deployed on many clients, or update of a reference in your Visual Studio solution?)

Comment: as these assemblies are 3rd party tools. So if i copy these to local directory than it will be copied version. (lets say it was release 2.0). After some time release 3.0 comes out and it has some bug fixing or optimizations. Now i would have to make up new version of my application to update these one or will have to provide all user (who have downloaded my application) with new assemblies to over-write these one's. even there is no change in my application.

Comment: my use case is that I don't want to package these assemblies with my application in any form. I want my application to load these when application is executing. That's what problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I rigth understoo your question is.

You have `C#` application that staticly linked via AddReference to some DLL's in your Visual Studio Solution. But on client machine those DLLs are not in the same location, but, by the way kn some known location.

To resolve this, should be enough to use

[AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx)

before actually calling

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

In this way, you will tell to your domain to lookup in custom look up path *too* for references.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this requires that other assemblies should be in the child directories of that directory. But required assemblies may not be in child directories.